# Why is my HTML form showing weird symbols?

Tags: html, forms, character

I'm running a simple example and am seeing the strange symbols (see attached image) for the form input areas instead of text.

[image]

I've tried adding the following to no avail:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
<body>
```

When viewing the following w3school examples, I'm also seeing these symbols. I've not had these issues before when viewing these resources; something must have changed?

[w3schools form example 1](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_reset)
[w3schools form example 2](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_submit)

What is causing this and how might I fix it?

Comment: Try writing the charset in capitals, we usually format them like that. It's definitely a charset issue though.

Comment: @ale8k Thanks, updated post with capitalized charset and still getting errors.

Comment: Ah ok, maybe silly question but you're also missing the final HTML tag, so your meta won't apply... Try that XD

Comment: @Ale8k Restarting the computer did the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like restarting the computer worked...